# python google cloud datastore delete multiple entities with a property equals a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore

I am wondering can I do batch delete entities of a kind when a property of these entities equal to a list of values in `google cloud datastore` using `Python`. `add_filter` can only add one property:value pair.

Is there an efficient way to add property:[values] as filters, and don't have to use a loop to go through each value; in each iteration, append a property:value pair as a filter, execute the query, get keys from the result entities and delete those entities based on the keys.

```
    def delete(self, vals):
        for val in vals:
            query = self.client.query(kind=self.kind)
            query.keys_only()
            query.add_filter('APAR_NAME', '=', primary_key)
            keys = list([entity.key for entity in query.fetch()])

            # [START batch_delete]
            self.client.delete_multi(keys)
            # [END batch_delete]
```

Comment: You mean the property is of `array` type matching `vals` or the property is a single value, present in the `vals` list?

Comment: Side comment: you can use `query.keys_only()` to directly obtain the list of entity keys instead of entities from `fetch()`, which you can then directly pass to `delete_multi()` without iterating through entities.

Comment: @DanCornilescu it is one property matching one value at a time, and I have a list of different values (`vals`) needed to be added as filters separately.

Comment: @DanCornilescu `keys_only()` only set the projection to include only keys. It still needs to use `query.fetch()` to get a list of entities with only keys.

Comment: Yes, but it's faster and cheaper.

Comment: updated the code using `query.fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay ...you want to delete multiple entries from google cloud datastore. For that you can use this

```
query = datastore_client.query(kind='Kind-name')
query.add_filter('property', '=', value)
query.add_filter('another property', '=', value)
for get_key in query.fetch():
    get_key_id = get_key.key.id
    delete = datastore_client.key("Kind-name", get_key_id)
    datastore_client.delete(delete)
```

this will delete all same value entries